# HTML5 Audio display only play pause and mute buttons

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm wondering if there's a quick and simple way to style the HTML5 audio element to display what I want. I was wondering if you could turn certain controls on and off, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I do not want a progress/track bar, or to display the time left. I just want a simple play/pause toggle button, and a mute/unmute toggle button.

That's all! Any ideas?

Comment: I answered it already. Here's the link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895581/html5-video-controls-mute-button/21500102#21500102

Answer (score 40):

Use this code it will serve your purpose.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <audio id="player" src="horse.ogg"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').muted=!document.getElementById('player').muted">Mute/ Unmute</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... It worked for me and i could substitute <button> by <a> and put a font-awesome "fa-volume-up" icon....

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [Media API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-elements) and build your own set of controls with the functionality you want. I've written about this: [Working with HTML5 multimedia components – Part 3: Custom controls](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html)  - which shows a video example, but you can just as easily build an audio one.

Comment: Link is gone, but available on the way back machine https://web.archive.org/web/20121215060538/http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-video-element.html