# HTML5 Video Controls (Mute Button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

```
$(".sound").click(function() {
  if ($(".intro-movie").prop('muted', true)) {

    $(".intro-movie").prop('muted', true);

    $(".sound").addClass("muted");

  } else {

    $(".intro-movie").prop('muted', false);

    $(".sound").removeClass("muted");
  }

});
```

Trying to get the sound icon ".sound" to mute or unmute the html5 video ".intro-movie" when clicked.

Comment: Maybe your `if ($(".intro-movie").prop('muted', true))` has to be `if ($(".intro-movie").prop('muted', false))`.

Now it seems: if(muted) then mute else unmute

Comment: if statemet should be changed. And this Q is duplicate of similar Qs [1st link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442427/muting-a-html5-audio-element-using-a-custom-button?lq=1), [2nd link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I tried may examples, and I finally made it myself. It works perfectly.

```
function mute() {
if(myaudio.muted)   {
    myaudio.muted=!myaudio.muted;
    document.getElementById("volume").style.backgroundImage = "url(resources/vol.png)";
}else{
    myaudio.muted=!myaudio.muted;
    document.getElementById("volume").style.backgroundImage = "url(resources/mute.png)";
}
```

}